# Use perl to find the run time of an AIFF Audio File

Tags: perl, aiff

What can I use to determine the run time of an AIFF audio file.  Preferably using Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Audio::Scan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Audio::Scan#AIFF) is a perl module available on CPAN which includes interfaces that return the length of an AIFF track in ms.